# JS array to PHP and update table in MYSQL with PDO

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have a form, where user can insert up to 4 age ranges. User can add or remove input fields dynamically.

I am trying to send the array to my PHP file and then insert it to database (insert new row for each range pair, lets say 1-3 and 4-6 will be on separate rows with correct user_id) with `PDO`.

The callback is success in PHP file, but nothing is inserted, which means it cannot get the values from `JS` and I am pretty lost how to send the array with the rest of the form data.

In `html` I have a button where, user can add fields dynamically and the ID will increment by 1 each time.

### HTML file

```
<div class="row default" id="childAgeRange1">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userProfileAgeFrom" name="userProfileAgeFrom[]" placeholder="Alates..." />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userProfileAgeTo" name="userProfileAgeTo[]" placeholder="Kuni..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

### My JS file:

```
    $(document).on("click", "#btnUpdateInformation", function (e) {


                var userProfileAgeFrom = $("input[name^='userProfileAgeFrom']").map(function (idx, ele) {
                    return $(ele).val();
                }).get();

                var userProfileAgeTo = $("input[name^='userProfileAgeTo']").map(function (idx, ele) {
                    return $(ele).val();
                }).get();

                var formData = {
                    'user_id'                     : $("#hiddenUserID").val(),
                    'userPassword'                : $('#userPassword').val(),
                    'userRetypePassword'          : $('#userRetypePassword').val(),
                    'userBirthCountry'            : $('#userBirthCountry').val(),
                    'userBirthCity'               : $('#userBirthCity').val(),
                    'userBirthAddress'            : $('#userBirthAddress').val(),
                    'UserZipCode'                 : $('#UserZipCode').val(),
                    'userFirstName'               : $('#userFirstName').val(),
                    'userLastName'                : $('#userLastName').val(),
                    'userSex'                     : $('#userSex').val(),
                    'userBirthDay'                : $('#userBirthDay').val(),
                    'userBirthMonth'              : $('#userBirthMonth').val(),
                    'userBirthYear'               : $('#userBirthYear').val(),
                    'userPhoneNr'                 : $('#userPhoneNr').val(),
                    'userPasswordConfirm'         : $('#userPasswordConfirm').val(),
                    'userQuote'                   : $('#userQuote').val(),
                    'userDescription'             : $('#userDescription').val(),
                    'userProfileAgeFrom'          : userProfileAgeFrom,
                    'userProfileAgeTo'            : userProfileAgeTo,
                    'userProfileWage'             : userFinalWage

                };
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PHP/updateUserProfile.php",
            data: formData,  
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    console.log("success");
                }else if(data.status == 'error'){
                    console.log("error");
                }else if(data.status == 'no_results'){
                    console.log("no results");
                }else if(data.status == 'results'){
                    console.log("there are results");
                }else if(data.status == 'password_matches'){
                    console.log("password matches");
                }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data){
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data);
            }
        });
        $('#btnUpdateInformation').unbind('click');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

### PHP file

```
        if(isset($_POST['userProfileAgeFrom']) && isset($_POST['userProfileAgeTo'])){
            $data = array( 
                $userProfileAgeFrom => $_POST['userProfileAgeFrom'], 
                $userProfileAgeTo => $_POST['userProfileAgeTo']
            );

            $user_profile_age_range = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE nanny_age_range SET age_minimum=:userProfileAgeFrom, age_maximum=:userProfileAgeTo WHERE user_id=:user_id ");
            $user_profile_age_range->bindparam(':userProfileAgeFrom', $userProfileAgeFrom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile_age_range->bindparam(':userProfileAgeTo', $userProfileAgeTo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile_age_range->bindparam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile_age_range->execute(); 
            $response_array['status'] = 'success';
        }
```

### And database Table:

[image]

EDIT
Console.log(formData) shows

```
UserZipCode
:
"11111"
userBirthAddress
:
"address"
userBirthCity
:
"c"
userBirthCountry
:
"c"
userBirthDay
:
"31"
userBirthMonth
:
"08"
userBirthYear
:
"1992"
userDescription
:
"description"
:
"x"
userLastName
:
"x"
userPassword
:
""
userPasswordConfirm
:
"xxxx"
userPhoneNr
:
"555555555555"
userProfileAgeFrom
:
"["1"]"
userProfileAgeTo
:
"["3"]"
userProfileWage
:
"9.60"
userQuote
:
"c"
userRetypePassword
:
""
userSex
:
"m"
user_id
:
"6"
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` return ?

Comment: @Cornwell var dump returns nothing, if I put it inside the function

Comment: Where are `$userProfileAgeFrom`, `$userProfileAgeTo` and `$user_id` defined? Your query also written as `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT INTO`. I clearly don't understand the question.

Comment: @Chay22, it should be update --- edited. The $userProfileAgeFrom and To comes from $_POST. They are defined like this 

$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
                $userProfileAgeTo= trim($_POST['userProfileAgeTo']);
                $userProfileAgeFrom= trim($_POST['userProfileAgeFrom']);

Comment: please show us the output of `console.log(formData);`

Comment: @raqulka put the var_dump before the `if`. Something is not being POSTed, we need to figure out what

Comment: @Cornwell it shows empty, no matter where I put it.

Comment: @lolka_bolka kindly see the edit

Comment: @raqulka Check the network tab of the developers tools. Is the data being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OP comment, `console.log(formData)` shows this:

```
userProfileAgeFrom: "["1"]"
userProfileAgeTo: "["3"]"
```

It means, now you have a JSON array in your values. So you need to decode it, and get the first value of it:

```
$userProfileAgeFrom = json_decode($_POST['userProfileAgeFrom'],true)[0], 
$userProfileAgeTo = json_decode($_POST['userProfileAgeTo'],true)[0]
```

**EDIT**

Based on OP comment.

So if you have more value in your `userProfileAgeFrom` and others, then iterate throught them:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['userProfileAgeFrom']); $i++) {
    $user_profile_age_range = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE nanny_age_range SET age_minimum=:userProfileAgeFrom, age_maximum=:userProfileAgeTo WHERE user_id=:user_id ");
    $user_profile_age_range->bindparam(':userProfileAgeFrom', $_POST['userProfileAgeFrom'][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $user_profile_age_range->bindparam(':userProfileAgeTo', $_POST['userProfileAgeTo'][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $user_profile_age_range->bindparam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $user_profile_age_range->execute();
}
```

**WARNING**

But this will bad, because all your rows will be the same because of `WHERE user_id=:user_id`

I think you should redesign your code.

Comment: but what if there are more? there an be up to 4 different ranges (sorry for the late reply).

Comment: Also tried, it and getting this: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: any suggestions how can I edit the correct rows, so they all wont be the same?

Comment: create a hidden field for all fields, like `<input type="hidden"  name="userProfileAgeToOld[]" value="<?php echo $oldValue[$keyOfOldValuesArray];?>" />` and say `WHERE userId = ... AND userProfileAge = userProfileAgeToOld[$i] AND ...` So update by all values.

Comment: so if I add hidden input and append the row id from database to the value. can I then say like update where user_id = user_id and age_range_id = id?

Comment: Perfect. With some extra edit I managed to get the system to work. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

The result of both $userProfileAgeFrom and $userProfileAgeTo are seems to array so the insertion will be work in a for loop. And hope the count of both this array are same.

```
$userProfileAgeFrom = $_POST['userProfileAgeFrom'];
$userProfileAgeTo = $_POST['userProfileAgeTo'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($userProfileAgeFrom); $i++) {
    $user_profile_age_range = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE nanny_age_range SET age_minimum=:userProfileAgeFrom, age_maximum=:userProfileAgeTo WHERE user_id=:user_id ");
    $user_profile_age_range->bindparam(':userProfileAgeFrom', $userProfileAgeFrom[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $user_profile_age_range->bindparam(':userProfileAgeTo', $userProfileAgeTo[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $user_profile_age_range->bindparam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $user_profile_age_range->execute();
}
```

Comment: this solution does update the values in DB, but it updates the rows to the same result- lets say I typed in 1-3 and 5-7, both the rows will be 5-7

Comment: This is because you are try to run an update query with user_id. Try to provide auto increment id for the table nanny_age_range and update based on that id.